# Trying to make a HelloWorld node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost

I done everything like say on nodejs.org tutorial for helloworld but I have a big problem. Please see the image below:

IMAGE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0zvc.png

I save example.js file into D: directory ...

How to start node.js code:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080);

console.log('Server started');
```

Answer (score 1):

You run `node example.js` from your command line (e.g. Windows Power Shell), not from inside the Node.js REPL.

Comment: thanks very very very much, why I need to use CMD and not note.js comand line

Comment: Because the node REPL is not a command line, it is somewhere you type JavaScript.

Comment: ok, I try this code but its not work: http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
 var start = new Date().getTime();
    response.end(start);
}).listen(8080);

Comment: ok, thanks nice... I can write javascript directly into note.js REPL

Comment: PLEASE HELP : Why I get this erros: http://i.imgur.com/h85awlo.png when I try to run this : https://github.com/jkvoorhis/userAuth/blob/master/index.js Please help, its so important to me to understand basic of this tehnologies

Answer (score 0):

From the command prompt navigate to D drive and then type `node example.js` to run your code.

When you use some package like `morgan` you need to install them before using them.Standard way of installing package is(again from command prompt) to navigate to your application folder and type `npm install <package-name>`. For further information look here:https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-install.html